# Can I sort finder results by multiple criteria at the same time?

Tags: finder, filesystem, search

The last files I interacted with are usually the ones I want to find quickly, but the column view in Finder only lets you sort by one criterion; (date added, date modified, date created etc.) at a time.

The problem here is a file that I recently modified won't be at the top of the "date added" list, and one I just downloaded won't even show up on the "date last opened". I'm still coping with the loss of recent files thanks to High Sierra update.

Is it possible to sort columns by two criteria at the same time? For example, sort downloads folder by date added OR modified?

A decent example of what I'm looking for would be similar to the dropbox mobile app, where it sorts by date added, but recently opened files go to the top of that list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes for some categories. At the top of the finder window, towards the middle, is an icon that lets you choose how to sort window. If you choose date added it will sort on that and divide the window into groups based on date added. You can then go to the column headers and click on the size, for example. Finder maintains the groupings but sorts on the size within each group.

Comment: This is so good..